# JSON response behaves weirdly in react native fetch

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am using fetch to send data to an API, when the data reaches the API it is validated and then a response is sent back with params that tell which data is valid and which is not.

The params seem to be sent back but i cannot access them.

This is the fetch:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/drivers', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Host': 'localhost:3000'
  },

  body: JSON.stringify({ 
    judet: judetText,
    numar: numarText,
    litere: litereText,
    taxi: isTaxi,
    token: device_id,
    key: api_key 
  })
})
.then(ApiUtils.checkStatus)          
.then((response) => response.json().then((json) => {
  console.log(json)
}))
```

And this is the logged result:

```
Promise {_45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null}
```

As you can see, "_65" is null

But if i expand it, this is what it shows me:

```
Promise
 _45: 0
_54: null
_65: Object
  already_added: false
  judet_invalid: true
  litere_invalide: false
  numar_invalid: true
  __proto__:Object
_81: 1
__proto__: Object
```

And those are the params that i try to access

If i run console.log(json["_65"]), it gives me null, like it is not expanded.

Why does the response behave like this? 
And how can i access those params?